# Formula to strip images from Chatter Posts

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, chatter, regular-expressions

I am building email notifications from Chatter Posts.  When the Post is created my notification Flow is writing the Feed Item Body to a Rich Text field on my Case which is included in my email.  If the Feed Items contains images these are replaced with

```
"<img src="/img/rte_broken_image.png" alt="This image is not available because: You don’t have the privileges to see it, or it has been removed from the system"></img>
```

The above is not generated until after the field is updated is written so in order to Substitute this I would need to run a second update on my Case field.

I would like to build an Apex method to strip the images from the Feed Item body and write this to my Case field - i.e

```
<img src="sfdc://06974000000n0zHAAQ" alt="image"></img>
```

I assume I could use a RegEx pattern match but I am struggling to figure out the syntax.

Comment: please use [edit] and show what you have tried. also stackoverflow is a good place to get regex help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out using the following

```java
String stripped;
String stripRegExp = '<img' + '(.+?)' + '</img>';
stripped = input.replaceAll(stripRegExp,'');
System.debug('stripped = ' + stripped);
```